Way to propagate movement along hyperbolic tessellation polygons or nodes, which moves faster than one-cell-at-a-time?
Wondering today, is there a way to have information travel faster than light on the "gear board"? The gear board being a hyperbolic tessellation shifting around like this MagicTile:

Such as, having one configuration which spans multiple gears/polygons, such that when a tail end of some polygon changes (ticks to a new configuration), it causes all other gears in the chain to tick a "message" across say 1000 polygons, to the head of the polygon, in one click.
Then the speed of light would be the speed at which going from one cell to the next is measured (like how Maurice Margenstern's Cellular Automata in Hyperbolic Spaces travel along the grid). And faster than the speed of light would be creating configurations so a tick could cause an effect many cells away. Is that possible in some sort of mathematical structure? Or is there some sort of limit due to "locality" that I'm overlooking?
Could use this idea for game mechanics.

Maybe this is along the right direction: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/klein.html
